# TabbedPage bar glitch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

When I open TabbedPage from another TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms for iOS the right part of bottom bar has that strange glitch/blink. Is there any solution to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried, not opening a TabbedPage from another TabbedPage, but rather replace the items in the Tab bar instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a need to reconsider UX in the app you are working on. Nested tabs are not intuitive and very confusing, beside the technical issues you can run into, here is a summary of notes from the [official Xamarin.Forms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page):

> It's recommended that a TabbedPage should be populated with
>   NavigationPage and ContentPageinstances only. This will help to ensure
>   a consistent user experience across all platforms.

---

> The TabbedPage does not support UI virtualization. Therefore,
>   performance may be affected if the TabbedPage contains too many child
>   elements.

---

> While it's acceptable to place a NavigationPage into a TabbedPage,
>   it's not recommended to place a TabbedPage into a NavigationPage. This
>   is because, on iOS, a UITabBarController always acts as a wrapper for
>   the UINavigationController. For more information, see Combined View
>   Controller Interfaces in the iOS Developer Library.